# AWS RDS Showing CPU spikes on a MySQL system every 5 minutes -- how can I track the cause?

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

I'm seeing a CPU spike every 5 minutes (though it's not FIXED on the 5 minutes, every so often it's 6 minutes between a spike, then 5, 5, 5 again).  None of my code runs on a 5 minute interval (it either runs statements EVERY minute, or every few HOURS).

This is what the graph looks like:
[image]

Is there any way I can analyze what is causing the CPU to spike like this?  Seeing a list of queries is good, but seeing their CPU impact is more what I'm after; a direct "A is causing B" way to dig down.

Does it exist?

Comment: Any scheduler jobs running on the database? Or primary-backup sync up?

Comment: Does the AWS RDS Dashboard show anything.  Failing that can you see anything interesting from running SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Do you remember whether you modified the default value for binlog_format?

Answer (score 0):

See the slow query list in mysql. Using that you could track which one is the culprit and taking more time to respond.